# Understanding PowerShell operators + and ,

Tags: powershell, operators

What is the exact difference between the `+` and the `,` operator in PowerShell? For instance when simply trying to concatenate two arrays both produce the same output, but I cannot sort the result of a `,` operation, only the result of a `+` operation:

```
$a = Get-ChildItem C:\
$b = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows
# Does not sort anything, actually is the same output as $a, $b
$a , $b | sort
# Sort actually works
$a + $b | sort
```

What confuses me even more is the fact, that both operators return the same type:

```
PS C:\> ($a,$b).getType().Name
Object[]
PS C:\> ($a+$b).getType().Name
Object[]
```

Comment: I have a suspicion: the result of `,` gets wrapped into an additional array, while the output of `+` is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both operators will produce an array in your scenario, but the comma operator doesn't interpolate arrays, so you're getting an array of arrays there, whereas the `+` operator appends the elements of the second array to those of the first array. It becomes clearer when you output the arrays in JSON format:

```
PS C:\> $a = 1, 2
PS C:\> $b = 3, 4
PS C:\> ($a, $b) | ConvertTo-Json
[
    {
        "value":  [
                      1,
                      2
                  ],
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "value":  [
                      3,
                      4
                  ],
        "Count":  2
    }
]
PS C:\> ($a + $b) | ConvertTo-Json
[
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
]
```

You can't just indiscriminately use the `+` operator, though, because it's overloaded and will produce different results depending on the type of the first operand:

```
PS C:\> 1 + @(3, 4)         # integer addition (fails)
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method
named 'op_Addition'.
At line:1 char:7
+ 1 + @(3, 4)
+       ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], ...
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

PS C:\> "1" + @(3, 4)       # string concatenation (succeeds)
13 4
PS C:\> @(1) + @(3, 4)      # array append (succeeds)
1
3
4
```